# When is $\frac{a^{b-1}+1}{a+b}$ an integer for positive integers $0<a<1000$ and $0<b\leq10$?

Tags: number-theory

When is $\frac{a^{b-1}+1}{a+b}$ an integer for positive integers $0<a<1000$ and $0<b\leq10$? (PLEASE REFER TO THE ALTERNATIVE REPRESENTATION)

I tried doing this for smaller numbers, but I don't see any clean way to deal with it. Another way I thought of was taking cases of $b$ and solving for possible values of $a$, however it seems to be too complicated.

**Alternative Representation:** When is $a^b\equiv b\bmod{a+b}$ for positive integers $0<a<1000$ and $0<b\leq10$?

Hoping I could get some help...

EDIT: I tried the same for $b=1,2,3$, but beyond that it seems to get too complicated.

Comment: The cases $b=1$ and $b=2$ are easy.

Comment: For odd $(b-1)$, this should be the case:
$$ ({a+b} )|(a+1)(a^{b-2}+a^{b-3}+a^{b-4}+...+1)$$ Maybe this helps?

Comment: @Crease What about even $(b-1)$?
I'm really confused right now...

Also, I tried for cases $b=2$ and $b=3$, but beyond that it becomes too complicated.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel What do you mean?

(Sorry, I'm a bit new to the community, so I don't really know how things work around here)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel But isn't it nearly the same thing? For example:
$a^b \equiv b \mod (a+b)$ simplifies to
$a^b \equiv -a \mod (a+b)$ and then dividing by a
$a^{b-1} \equiv -1 \mod (a+b)$ and reexpressed as 
$a^{b-1} = x(a+b) - 1$ (for an integer x)
$x = \frac{a^{b-1}+1}{a+b}$ which has to be an integer which was what I was asking for...

Comment: Oh ok... @ParclyTaxel Can I ask a new question with what I want, since this one has a different solution, and I can't seem to figure it out... Or would someone else help me with my question in this question itself?

Comment: Better to accept the answer given.

Comment: @MathIsEZ Can you edit your question with the attempt for $b=1,2$ and $3$? It will be helpful to get the easy cases out of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a \equiv -b (\mod a+b)$
$a^{b-1} \equiv (-b)^{b-1} (\mod a+b)$
It is given that $a^{b-1} \equiv -1 (\mod a+b)$
⇒ $(-b)^{b-1} \equiv -1 (\mod a+b)$

$a+b$ divides $(-b)^{b-1}+1$. This simplifies the given condition.
Substitute the values of $b$ and solve.
Example for $b=3$, we have $a+3$ divides $10$. Therefore $a=2,7$ when $b=3$. Similarly solve for other values of $b$.

Comment: but doesn't the ordered pair $(a,b) = (27,3)$ work too?
Also, from where did the first statement come from?

Comment: @MathIsEZ $(27,3)$ does not work.

Comment: @MathIsEZ The first statement $a \equiv -b (\mod a+b)$ simply means $a+b$ divides $a+b$.

Comment: I made a python code for the same:

`for n in range(1,1000):
  mcount = 0
  for m in range(1,11):
    if (mcount < 1):
      if (n**m) % (n+m) == m:
        print(n,m)
        mcount += 1`

Comment: Any help? I think I simplified the problem incorrectly...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yeah, it doesn't work... I edited the question btw and I think 27,3 works correctly for it...